# Phalcon with Cassandra PDO?

Tags: php, cassandra, phalcon

How to use Phalcon with [Cassandra PDO](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/)?

Comment: What question are you actually asking here? I something not working for you? Have you run into a particular problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment [Phalcon](http://www.phalconphp.com/en/) does not support Cassandra PDO - actually you are the first person to ever ask for it :)

You can however implement it yourself using these guides

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/db.html#implementing-your-own-adapters
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/db.html#implementing-your-own-dialects

Sample implementations can be found in our incubator repo here:

https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Db/Adapter

Comment: I'm actually looking at implementing it as well...  Thanks for the links.

Comment: I want it two, Cassandra will became more popular in future

Comment: Looking for a cassandra PDO for phacon too